# Программа для тестов Python

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Пишу программу для прохождения тестирования на Python, но не получается правильно продумать работу с GUI.Приходится кпждый раз закрывать окно, чтобы переключиться на следующий вопрос. Как лучше справиться с поставленной задачей? Наверняка я упускаю простое и лаконичное решение по не опытности.

```
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import *

def count1(event):
    global ans1, answers, score
    if ans1 == answers[0]:
        score += 1


def count2(event):
    global ans1, answers, score
    if ans1 == answers[1]:
        score += 1



def count3(event):
    global ans1, answers, score
    if ans1 == answers[0]:
        score += 1


score = 0 
tests = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for i in range(0, 3):
    question = tests.readline()
    ans1 = tests.readline().strip()
    ans2 = tests.readline().strip()
    ans3 = tests.readline().strip()
    answers = [ans1, ans2, ans3]
    shuffle(answers)
    print(question)
    shuffle(answers)
    print(*answers, sep='\n')

    root = Tk()
    lab = Label(root, text=question, font="Arial 18")
    lab.pack()

    answ1 = Button(root)
    answ1['text'] = answers[0]
    answ1.bind('<Button-1>', count1)
    answ1.pack()

    answ2 = Button(root)
    answ2['text'] = answers[1]
    answ2.bind('<Button-1>', count2)
    answ2.pack()

    answ3 = Button(root)
    answ3['text'] = answers[2]
    answ3.bind('<Button-1>', count3)
    answ3.pack()

root.mainloop()
print(score)
```

Comment: Я советую попробовать PyQt5. Огромное количество примеров и информации. Если знаешь синтаксис С++, то у Qt просто божественные доки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно не загонять программу в цикл и уж тем более не создавать каждый раз главное окно, а:

1) Либо скрывать виджеты (пожалуй лучший способ) с помощью метода `pack_forget` Например:

```
from tkinter import *

def hide_me(event):
    event.widget.pack_forget()

root = Tk()
btn=Button(root, text="Click")
btn.bind('<Button-1>', hide_me)
btn.pack()
btn2=Button(root, text="Click too")
btn2.bind('<Button-1>', hide_me)
btn2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Подробней [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible).

2) Либо удалять их через метод `destroy`. Только в отличии от `pack_forget` вы их не сможете потом вернуть назад.

3) Либо создавать дочерние окна через `Toplevel()`. Например:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new window", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Подробней [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306631/how-do-i-create-child-windows-with-python-tkinter/15306785#15306785).